# How to handle flag/exception values

Tags: paraview

In Paraview, I am working with a dataset that uses the value -99999 as a flag value.  I'd like to be able to manipulate the dataset without these values causing issues with things like glyphs and colorbars.  Nominally, I'd like the data to be "ignored".

A little about the data:  I've got both scalar and vector point data, sitting on a fixed 2D spatial mesh at set temporal intervals.

Although -99999 is very far beyond the values the data might otherwise show, using a threshold filter isn't an option because the flag can occur at different places at different times.  The way Paraview's threshold filter works means that the point ID to a fixed point in space will change as the number of filtered points changes through time.

In case it matters, data are in a netCDF file that is read in via an XMF header file and the XDMF Reader since the CF reader doesn't work (possibly because of my unstructured triangular mesh).  The netCDF data have the _FillValue global attribute, however this doesn't appear to be getting picked up on by Paraview.

Comment: Are you using the netCDF/CF reader? If I recall correctly, the netCDF reader that uses the CF convention has an option to select an “invalid” value that will be translated to `NaN`, at which point ParaView will probably handle it correctly.

Comment: I knew I forgot to mention something.  No, XMDF Reader, I'll update the question.

Comment: @KennethMoreland Would using a different data type make this problem tractable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Programmable Filter` to replace values below -99999 by NaN. Providing the data is not a `vtkMultiblockDataSet`, you can use the following script in the programmable filter :

```py
import numpy as np
from vtk.numpy_interface import dataset_adapter as dsa

# name of the array
name = 'name'
# limit
limit = -99999

array = inputs[0].PointData[name].copy()
array[array<=limit] = np.nan
out = dsa.WrapDataObject(self.GetOutput())
out.PointData.append(array, name)
```

Note: if data of interest is a Cell Data, replace `PointData` by `CellData` in the script.

Note 2: the script was tested on ParaView 5.6.

Comment: Confirmed, deleting my old comment to avoid confusion.